# Whats the difference between a normal python property, and a bpy.prop property?

Tags: python, properties

I know that this may be a silly theoric question, but I'm trying to learn  Blender scripting the best I can. And I found the API not always have the answers to the questions I ask myself.

So, what is the difference between a normal property defined in python and a bpy.props. property?

I mean, we can have a Class A, and in this class can have both a string property like

```
Class A:
    string_property_normal = "hi"
    string_property_blender : bpy.props.StringProperty()
```

Both holds a string. From what I know,bpy.props. are registered with Blender's RNA API, I assume that this makes them able for showing in the Blender's UI, being animated, etc.

But, here my (maybe silly) questions:

- Should I only be using bpy.props when I want to show them in the Blender's UI?
- Does normal/classic properties (not defined with bpy.ops) "serialized"/saved into the .blend file? (I mean, if I create a Class A object, and I make changes to `string_property_normal`, will those changes be lost or not saved with the blend file whenever I open again the file? Are they safe or should I limit their use as some kind of  "constants" or such?
- Should I only be using bpy.props properties or is it ok to write "normal" properties without bpy.props? If so, which are some uses when you use "normal" properties over bpy.props?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I think the serialization is exactly the problem. If you want to use a constant in your code, it should be fine to use normal string property as it is registred again on blender startup and stays the same (for ex. spacing value betweeen inserted nodes). Blender properties are kept within the blend file and as such are used for variables changing with the context so you would use for ex. CollectionProperty for dynamically changing list of objects

Comment: @JiříHonzák thank you for the comment and the help mate. I've been doing some tests and (someone correct me if I'm wrong but), seems we are not able to change the value of the "normal" properties (at least when executing operators). Im printing one via layout.label() and it always have its default/init value.

Comment: The two strings have different properties and functions, like default value, description,... . For example, the bpy one can insert keyframes (str can't) and use them display on the panel directly, the other cannot.